# Remove enter space only with empty row in one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in Excel. This table I load to SQL Server through SSIS. In the table is column TEXT that contains multiple sentences in one cell separated by enter spaces (alt + enter). My table looks like this:

| NAME | ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 125 | TEXT TEXT TEXT |

But sometimes I have in column TEXT more enter spaces without text, like this:

| NAME | ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 125 | TEXT TEXT TEXT |

I need to remove excess line breaks but keep enter space after each TEXT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace consecutive duplicate letters with a single letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866993/replace-consecutive-duplicate-letters-with-a-single-letter)